# I always get a '255' value as keycode of these characters. How to retrieve the right keycode?

Tags: .net, vb.net, char, character, keycode

I don't understand the next issue.

I'm using the function [VkKeyScanEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646332%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the virtual-keycode of a character, then I get the low-order byte of the value that returns the function to retrieve the keycode.

All works as expected but with these characters I always get the same keycode `255`

> áéíóú ÁÉÍÓÚ àèìòù ÀÈÌÒÙ äëïÖÜ ÄËÏÖÜ

Both the low-order byte and the high-order byte that returns me the `VkKeyScanEx` function are `255` for those chars.

I don't know what to do with that `255`, 'cause I would like to print the character like this:

```
MsgBox(Convert.ToChar(255))
```

I don't know if this is an error or is the proper value, anyways I've tried to specify my keyboard layout (which is `10`) using the [GetKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function but I still get the same `255` value.

Someone could explain me if the value is right and what means that `255` keycode?, if not, How to transform those chars in the right keycode?

---

This is the code that I'm testing:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Shown

        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

        Dim Characters As Char() =
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ñÑçÇ áéíóú ÁÉÍÓÚ àèìòù ÀÈÌÒÙ äëïÖÜ ÄËÏÖÜ º\'¡`+´-.,ª!·$%&/()=?¿".ToCharArray

        For Each c As Char In Characters
            sb.AppendFormat("Character: {0}", CStr(c))
            sb.AppendLine()
            sb.AppendFormat("KeyCode  : {0}", CStr(GetKeyCode(c, GetKeyboardLayout(IntPtr.Zero))))
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString)
            sb.Clear()
        Next c

    End Sub

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Private Shared Function VkKeyScanEx(
                            ByVal c As Char,
                            Optional ByVal KeyboardLayout As IntPtr = Nothing
    ) As Short
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetKeyboardLayout", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Private Shared Function APIGetKeyboardLayout(
                            Optional ByVal idThread As IntPtr = Nothing
    ) As UInteger
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Translates a character to the corresponding keycode. 
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Function GetKeyCode(ByVal c As Char,
                                      Optional ByVal KeyboardLayout As IntPtr = Nothing) As Short
        Return BitConverter.GetBytes(VkKeyScanEx(c)).First
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Retrieves the active input locale identifier (formerly called the keyboard layout).
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Function GetKeyboardLayout(Optional ByVal idThread As IntPtr = Nothing) As Short
        Return BitConverter.GetBytes(APIGetKeyboardLayout(idThread)).First
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646332.aspx) says:

> If the function finds no key that translates to the passed character code, both the low-order and high-order bytes contain –1.

Which is what you're getting, interpreted as an unsigned byte. I guess your keyboard (or the layout you're specifying) does not have keys for those characters.

Comment: thanks for clarify. In my keyboard (Spanish layout) I need to press the keys `´` + `A` then I get an `Á`, The  `VkKeyScanEx` function can't return the keycode for that char? I'm missing something more?

Comment: Quite possibly. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646332.aspx) says there are flags for CTRL, ALT, SHIFT, "Hankaku", and a couple of driver-reserved flags. Doesn't look like there's one for ´. You could try handling your form's `KeyDown` event, and then pressing those keys. You can then look at `e.KeyCode` etc.